# Does the potential energy of a system of objects depend on the reference point or the nature of force existing between them?

Tags: potential-energy

Does the potential energy of a system consisting of two charged bodies depend on the reference point or the nature of force existing between them(attractive or repulsive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the potential energy of a set of particles is defined as the work done to bring them from infinity to their current positions.

If the particles repel, you will have to do some work to overcome the repulsion, so the potential energy is positive.

If they attract, then they actually do work *for* you as they come together (since they pull you along). 
In other words, the amount of work you have to do is *negative* in this case,
so the potential energy is negative.

One slight complication is that anyone is free to add a constant number to this definition of potential energy, 
because experiments always measure an energy *difference* between two states, and any constant term will cancel out in the difference.
(I assume that's what you mean by reference point?)

Comment: Can we define the (change in)potential energy set of the particles at particular position as the work required to bring them from any arbitrary point to their current position?

Comment: Yes. And if someone else chooses a different arbitrary point, that's equivalent to adding a constant to your definition.

Comment: I could not understand the last part of your comment.

Comment: I was just pointing out that the freedom to choose an arbitrary starting point is the _same_ as the freedom to add a constant to the potential.
(Because, if somebody chooses a starting point that is different from yours, his work calculations will all differ from yours by a constant.)

Comment: One more query. The potential energy of a set of particles is defined as the work required to bring them from infinity to their current positions. If the force between the particles is attractive, they do work on their own and no work is done by us. Then how are we doing negative work?

Comment: If the items were pulled together, they would have KE from the attraction.  To create a system with the same particles at rest requires that we remove the KE from them.  That can be imagined as us doing negative work on the particles or the particles doing positive work on u.